# $R(X,Y)f = 0$ holds for any connections?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, connections

We define $R_{XY}$ for any connections $\nabla$ as following
$$R_{XY}:=\nabla_{X}\nabla_{Y} - \nabla_{Y}\nabla_{X} - \nabla_{\left[X,Y\right]}$$
Then can we claim that $R_{XY} f = 0?$ since the following computation
$$R_{XY}f = \nabla_{X}\nabla_{Y}f - \nabla_{Y}\nabla_{X}f - \nabla_{\left[X,Y\right]} f = \nabla_{X}(Yf) - \nabla_{Y}(Xf) - \left[X,Y\right](f)  = X(Yf) - Y(Xf) - \left[X,Y\right](f) = 0.$$
I am not very sure about this conclusion.

Comment: It seems fine to me as long as $f$ is a smooth real-valued function on your manifold.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch I hope so. Thank you!

Comment: Usually in the definition of the Riemann tensor $R(X,Y)=\nabla_X\nabla_Y-\nabla_Y\nabla_X-\nabla_{[X,Y]}$, the symbol $\nabla$ is used to specifically denote the operator on vector fields, not on functions.